# Apache virtual host port forwarding without showing the port number

Tags: apache-http-server, port-forwarding, virtual-host, port-redirection

I've set up the virtual host for under Apache.

config is

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
      DocumentRoot /var/www/abc
```

But my website runs on 8090

I should get the website when somebody types the `mydomain.com`

and browser should NOT show `maydomain.com:8090`

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

If you get your website using only `http://mydomain.com/`, then by definition your web server has to serve it on port 80. If you can get your website only via port 8090, then that 8090 *will* have to be in the URL. There is no way around it.

You could in theory arrange for port forwardings or proxying or something similar, but at the end that means that *something* will then listen on port 80 and will have to forward that traffic. The web browser will always connect to port 80 if no other port is specified in the URL.